# Show output only if both words match using grep

Tags: grep, scientific-linux

If `packagehello` does not match, the output is still displayed.

**Aim:** to see `no output` in situation 2

*Situation 1:*

```
user@hostname ~]$ sudo yum list 'package*'
packagehello
packagehello
package2world
packagehello
package2world
```

*Situation 2:*

```
user@hostname ~]$ sudo yum list 'package*' | grep -E 'package1.*|package2.*'
package2world
package2world
```

How to show the output `only if` both words match using `grep`?

Comment: `packagehello` matches neither `package1.*` not `package2.*`. Are you sure of your output?

Comment: Question has been updated. The expectation is to see no output in situation 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo yum list 'package*' |
  grep -E 'package1.*package2|package2.*package1'
```

or using multiple `grep`:

```
sudo yum list 'package*' |
  grep 'package1' |
  grep 'package2'
```